# How to pass multiple where in routes Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I want to pass two where arguments in route but it is working for one only.
Below is my code.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}'.'.example.com'], function() {

    // Here goes all your subdomain handling

    // Then handle subdomain requests that where not found
    Route::get('{slug}', function($subdomain, $slug) {
        return redirect(\URL::to('http://example.com/'.$slug));
    })->where('slug', 'admin')->where('slug', 'distributor');
});
```

For Example:

`www.ez.example.com/distributor` redirecting to `www.example.com/distributor`

but `admin` is not working

it is working for distributor only. I want it to work for admin too,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're only getting it to work for one of the where's is because the where's get stored in an array and are keyed by the name you pass to it (i.e. `'slug'`) so the 2nd one is overrides the 1st.

The `where()` method on the `Route` takes a regular expression so what you can do is:

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($subdomain, $slug) {
    return redirect(\URL::to('http://example.com/'.$slug));
})->where('slug', 'admin|distributor');
```